# Getting Error "Additional information: Reference to undeclared entity 'acirc'. Line 3325, position 145."

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following code to read live xml url.

```
 XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();

 xmlDoc.Load("http://deluxecomm.com.au/feed.php");
```

I am getting the following error 
Getting Error "Additional information: Reference to undeclared entity 'acirc'. Line 3325, position 145."

What I am doing wrong here!!!

Comment: That means the their XML is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read HTML into an XML Data Document.  HTML is not XML.  They are both markup languages, but the two are not interchangeable.

You should look into using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hello,Now I am not getting the error Reference to undeclared entity 'acirc'. Line 3325, position 145." Now I able to bind the datagrid by with the data from live xml(online url) file, but it is truncating some data.